# Not getting data from ajax call to controller as array data in MVC c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

### ##  AJAX CALL in cshtml page ##

```
function ValidateData() {
            var editedRows = [];
            $("#eventsTable tbody tr").each(function () {
                editedRows.push({
                    PK_WS_Event: $(this).find("td:eq(1)")[0].innerText,
                    Act_Id: $(this).find("td:eq(2)")[0].innerText,
                    WeeklyStatus: $(this).find("td:eq(3) option:selected").text()
               == "--Select--" ? "" : $(this).find("td:eq(3) 
          option:selected").text(),
                    WeeklyStatusSubType: $(this).find("td:eq(4)  
         option:selected").text() == "--Select--" ? "" : $(this).
         find("td:eq(4) option:selected").text(),
                    AccountName: $(this).find("td:eq(5)")[0].innerText,
                    AccountNumber: $(this).find("td:eq(6)")[0].innerText,
                    WeeklyStatusDesc: $(this).find("td:eq(7)")
             [0].textContent.trim(),
                });
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "/WeeklyStatus/IndexSubmit",
                data: JSON.stringify({ editedRows: editedRows }),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (response) { 
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('fail');
                }
            });
        }



    ## Server Code Controller and ##
    ----------
       [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult IndexSubmit(IList<WeeklyStatusEvents> 
          editedRows)
            {
                return null;
            }
```

My ViewModel as like as below..

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
    public int SelectedStatusId { get; set; }
    public int SelectedSubTypeId { get; set; }


    public List<WeeklyStatusEvents> statusEvents { get; set; }

}
```

And WeeklyStatusEvents model as shown below

```
public class WeeklyStatusEvents
{

    public string PK_WS_Event { get; set; }
    public string Act_Id { get; set; }
    //public bool INDExcludeFromRpt { get; set; }
    public string WeeklyStatus { get; set; }
    public string WeeklyStatusSubType { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string WeeklyStatusDesc { get; set; }


}
```

#### So Here, I am getting count as 0......

I have created class with all these properties. and Same property name I was used in ajax call as well.

Even I am not getting data. Can you provide the solution what i missed to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
data: JSON.stringify({ editedRows: editedRows }),
```

with

```
data: JSON.stringify(editedRows),
```

The difference is that you want to send an array of objects instead of an object which contains an array.

In order to see the diferences between those two, I recommend you to inspect what the following lines return:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(editedRows) 
console.log(JSON.stringify({ editedRows: editedRows })
```

And add [FromBody] in front of your parameter in your action.

Comment: Convert IList<WeeklyStatusEvents>  to List<WeeklyStatusEvents> and try again.

Comment: How WeeklyStatusEvents class looks like? Modify the question and also include that?

Comment: public class WeeklyStatusEvents
    {
        
        public string PK_WS_Event { get; set; }
        public string Act_Id { get; set; }
        //public bool INDExcludeFromRpt { get; set; }
        public string WeeklyStatus { get; set; }
        public string WeeklyStatusSubType { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string WeeklyStatusDesc { get; set; }
    

    }

Comment: This is my class... And I am using ViewModel means inside my view model, this is a sub list....

 public class ReportViewModel
    {
        public int SelectedStatusId { get; set; }
        public int SelectedSubTypeId { get; set; }
     

        public List<WeeklyStatusEvents> statusEvents { get; set; }

}

Comment: Add [FromBody] in front of your List<WeeklyStatusEvents> and try again.

Comment: Combine my answers and be sure you have this line of code in your javascript file: data: JSON.stringify(editedRows)

Comment: [FromBody] working bro... Thanks a lot... Appreciate your help.

Comment: Your welcome. Can you mark the answer as 'correct' if it solved your problem?

Comment: I am not able to provide vote since I am new to this site.. So it not taking votes

Comment: Bro, I wanted to pass one more flag just like Type in the same ajax call along with present data... How to do that?

Comment: Simply add another property in your class and send it from you JavaScript code.

Comment: I am passing list class.. so it has list... But I need only one flag... I think its might not good to add a property in class since if we pass 10 records, every record will have that flag... That not useful i think... Can u add your suggestions...

Comment: An idea would be to send to the server a object which two properties: a list and a flag. Keep in mind that you also have to change the server code in order to accept an object of a class that contains a list and a flag.

Answer (score 0):

Add [FromBody] in front of your List and try again

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IndexSubmit([FromBody] List<WeeklyStatusEvents> obj)
{
   Vreturn null;
}
```